# How to run a server to accept API calls from another application using an existing Java class?

Tags: java, networking, frameworks

I have wrote a java class which accepts some input and gives some output.

I have another web application, which would like to send a request json containing the input data to a server and receive response json containing the output data. The server will receive the request, parse it and format the input for the java class, and then utilize the java class to calculate the output, and finally format the response and send the response to the web application.

However, I am stuck at how to write this server.

Currently I have some ideas in mind: 
 
1) Using a big frame work such as Play or Spring -> but usually those requires tomcat to deploy, which is too heavy for my little java class 
 
2) Write my own HTTP server with java, according to this guide http://oreilly.com/catalog/javanp2/chapter/ch11.html

Anyone knows that if there is a light weighted java framework or java library that I can use for my purpose?  
 
By utilize which, I can simply write my server and run my service, but do not need to handle too much networking and threading?

Thanks for helping me out! All answer appreciated!

Comment: A popular, light weight http server is http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/.

Answer (score 3):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is an example of a server that can be run [embedded](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty). This removes needing to build a .war and deploy it to a servlet container such as Tomcat. Here are [some examples](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html).